# Scaling a centered image in Bootstrap relative to the background

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I want an image to be centered within a div. The div takes up the entire width of the screen (either w-100 or mw-100), and only a portion of the height. The image resizes to the browser window.

Is there a way I can set the percent scale of the image, while having it be centered? I've tried mx-auto, my-auto, and img-fluid. This works to center the image when resizing the window, but this takes up the entire div. I want more of the background showing (eg. to allow a color to surround the image).

Is there a way I can either:

1. Set the % scale of the image (eg. 500x200 -> 250x100) while keeping it to the center of the div

or

2. Enlarge the div background

Example code:

```
  <div className="w-100" style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
    <img src="img.jpg" className="img-fluid mx-auto my-auto d-block" />
  </div>
```

I have tried setting the height and max-height in both the div and image, but to no avail.

edit:

Picture for clarification:

[image]

Suppose the entire rectangle is the webpage. The green section is the div where I want the picture. The bright red square is the picture itself. What I want, simply, is to be able to scale the image and have it stay centered within the div (right side shows this). I would also like dynamic resizing if the browser window is changed.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your desire result? Little hard to understand your issue. Maybe this trick will be helpful: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/ + `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: A screenshot of the problem and of the intended result would be very helpful to understand the issue. 

So far, I would be inclined to use some padding on the parent element containing the image.

Comment: I've added an image

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a `screenshot` of your problem which will make us understand the problem you are facing in more easier way.

What I am understanding is that you want your `red` background to show while resizing the screen so you can add className `w-75` to your `<img>` tag so it will help in showing your background while resizing the screen and your `img` will always remain at center.

```
<div className="w-100" style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
 <img src="img.jpg" className="img-fluid mx-auto my-auto d-block w-75"  />
```

[JSFIDDILE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/0dunck5L/1/)

Comment: What you have is similar to what I have. The only issue is changing w-75 also affects the div as well. Is there a way to set the div at a certain size, and then scale the image independently while still having it remain centered? Eg. what if I want more color at the bottom or top? I tried using mb and pb paddings, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you want div to be a certain size you can give that div a `className` of `w-75` instead of `w-100` and the image will remain at center of your certain size `div` and then if you want to have space at top or at bottom you can use `p-md-5` to your `img` ClassName upto the medium devices and then add `p-2` centering `image` for small devices, Really sorry if this does not answer your question pal!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using

```
width: fit-content;
```

By adding this property to child element, it will acquire full space as parent element.

https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content